# Is this a bug of the typescript compiler? Higher-order function using union types

Tags: typescript, function, union, higher-order-functions

```
function toNumber(input: 'a' | 'b'): number {
  switch (input) {
    case 'a':
      return 1;

    case 'b':
      return 2;
  }
}

function bar(toNumber: (input: 'a' | 'b' | 'c') => number): number {
  return toNumber('c');
}

bar(toNumber); // No typescript error, but returns `undefined`
```

I expect TypeScript to report an error the last line. There's clearly a type error there.

Is this a bug of the typescript compiler? If so, can you link me to an open issue in the compiler repo or should I create one?

Comment: I tested this with the latest version of typescript, 5.2.2

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFOA5EBbARgUwE4AUMYADiFAFyIDkAhtYgD41bUCUVYmueiA3gChEiAM4B3GFAgALREVLk2-IcMQRaInDXoUVqxHhxQQeJAEYA3AL1qNW6q137hh46cQAmK8IC+AvwKgkLAIiFi0hCjo2PhU8mSU2gzMDsk0EOyIALwAfIhcMXgc+dz4yi5GJkhRpYTUGWxWAeGRaLWNQA

Comment: Works (errors) for me. Check your config.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript only ignores this error when the option `strict` is set to `false`.

(Thanks @andy-ray for pointing that out in the comments)